# Operation must use an Updateable Query / SQL - VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, vba

I am trying to create a very dynamic macro that will update different tables in a Database, depending on what the user chooses. Each table has of course distinct titles and information. I'm having a problem with the update (when the user adds new records to an old Table). This is  part of the code, the problem is when it gets to the ".update", I get the "Operation must use an Updateable Query" error.

```vb
Dim DBCnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sQRY As String
Dim FilePath, Titulo, Tabla As String
Dim LastRow, LastColumn, TotalRecords, Id As Long

Set DBCnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set RecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
DBCnn.Mode = adModeReadWrite
DBCnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";"

sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Customers" & Tabla ' & " WHERE PopID = " & lngid

RecSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
RecSet.Open _
    Source:=sQRY, _
    ActiveConnection:=DBCnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynaset, _
    LockType:=adLockOptimistic


Do While Range("A" & LastRow).Value <> ""
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
With RecSet
    .AddNew
    .Fields("Id") = Range("A" & LastRow).Value
    .Fields("Name") = Range("B" & LastRow).Text
    .Fields("Age") = Range("C" & LastRow).Value
    .Update '(Here's my error)
End With
LastRow = LastRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: What type is your database file, ".accdb"? isn't it open or protected? your code looks fine except `CursorType:=adOpenDynaset` which I don't recognise- shouldn't it be `adOpenDynamic`??

Comment: as far as I know its not protected, and I'm running it while its closed. Also, I changed it to Dynamic and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: what kind is your database?

Comment: its just an access Database

Comment: So, I use similar code except `DBCnn.Mode` and `RecSet.CursorLocation` which have default value in my situation. But I checked your settings with my code and it's seems that your code is correct. In my humble opinion there is something wrong with your database/table settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discard this line:

```
RecSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

Or try it like this instead:

```
RecSet.CursorLocation = adUseServer
```

See the Remarks section at [CursorLocation Property (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee252442%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) on MSDN:

*"If the **CursorLocation** property is set to **adUseClient**, the recordset will be accessible as read-only, and recordset updates to the host are not possible."*

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating a string here - "SELECT * FROM Customers" & Tabla , but I don't see where Tabla is being provided.

Have you tried running the query directly in Access?
Also, have you tried changing cursortype yet?
       http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_cursortype.asp